# Covering a graph with cliques

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

[Bron–Kerbosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) algorithm can be used to find all maximal [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in an undirected graph.

Next, I need to find a set of disjoint maximal cliques that cover the graph. Without the disjointness condition, the set of all maximal cliques covers the graph, since each vertex forms a 1-clique and so is contained in at least one clique, hence in some maximal clique.

Is there any known way to acieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every graph can be covered by vertex-disjoint cliques which are maximal. As a counterexample, take two copies of $K_3$ and identify one vertex of the left one with one vertex of the right one. Every clique in this graph is contained in a $3$-clique, but the only vertex-disjoint covers always contain cliques of size no larger than $2$.

So, your question is sortof ill-defined. Of course, you can cover the graph in this example by a $K_3$ and a $K_2$, which feels like the best you could want. I speculate that you might want the following:

> Define a covering $\mathcal C$ of $G$ by cliques to be maximal if for all cliques $C_1, C_2\in\mathcal C$, the union of the vertices of $C_1$ and $C_2$ does not induce a clique in $G$.

But a covering of this kind can be found easily by a greedy algorithm: Start at any vertex and find some maximal clique that it is contained in, then remove the vertices of this clique from the graph and repeat.